# How can I print to standard error in C with 'printf'?

Tags: c, printf, stderr

In C, printing to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (stdout) is easy, with `printf` from `stdio.h`.

However, how can I print to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) (stderr)? We can use `fprintf` to achieve it apparently, but its syntax seems strange. Maybe we can use `printf` to print to standard error?

Comment: What's so "strange" about it's syntax? It's print *where*, *how* and *what*.

Comment: I am focusing on it. The only problem which is arising from the question, that you find the solution "strange". Otherwise there is no question. Use `fprintf`.

Comment: @Eugene. I agree with you. I thought it was strange as I did not realize stderr is a FILE :)

Comment: @Schilive Thanks for letting me know - I deleted mine now as well.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

The syntax is almost the same as `printf`. With `printf` you give the string format and its contents ie:

```
printf("my %s has %d chars\n", "string format", 30);
```

With `fprintf` it is the same, except now you are also specifying the place to print to:

```
FILE *myFile;
...
fprintf(myFile, "my %s has %d chars\n", "string format", 30);
```

Or in your case:

```
fprintf(stderr, "my %s has %d chars\n", "string format", 30);
```

Answer (score 62):

Some examples of formatted output to stdout and stderr:

```
printf("%s", "Hello world\n");              // "Hello world" on stdout (using printf)
fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Hello world\n");     // "Hello world" on stdout (using fprintf)
fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Stack overflow!\n"); // Error message on stderr (using fprintf)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
    printf( "hello " );
    fprintf( stderr, "HELP!" );
    printf( " world\n" );
    return 0;
}

$ ./a.exe
HELP!hello  world
$ ./a.exe 2> tmp1
hello  world
$ ./a.exe 1> tmp1
HELP!$
```

1. stderr is usually unbuffered and stdout usually is. This can lead to odd looking output like this, which suggests code is executing in the wrong order. It isn't, it's just that the stdout buffer has yet to be flushed.
   Redirected or piped streams would of course not see this interleave as they would normally only see the output of stdout only or stderr only.
2. Although initially both stdout and stderr come to the console, both are separate and can be individually redirected.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to modify current code and just for debug usage.

Add this macro:

```
#define printf(args...) fprintf(stderr, ##args)
// Under GCC

#define printf(args...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
// Under MSVC
```

Change `stderr` to `stdout` if you want to roll back.

It's helpful for debug, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: You could also give it a separate name, perhaps `eprintf` or something. (:O This is actually GCC (3.2)'s example of a variadic macro: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` is not MSVC-specific because it is defined in [section 6.10.3 paragraph 5 of C99](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.10.3p5)

Answer (score 2):

You may know [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). It's basically the same thing with `fprintf`. The first argument is the destination (the file in the case of `fprintf` i.e. `stderr`), the second argument is the format string, and the rest are the arguments as usual.

I also recommend [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: This is unrelated to the OP and is worded confusingly.  sprintf will "print" to a string and cannot print to stderr.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, no one has mentioned `eprintf()` yet, which is the same thing as `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.

```
eprintf("ERROR: You have caused an error!!1!");
```

Quick tip: If you are using stderr for debugging, you can use the `__LINE__` macro

```
#define printfError(str, ...) eprintf("ERROR at line " #__LINE__ ": " str, __VA_ARGS__)

printfError("Division by zero"); // "ERROR at line 2: Division by zero
```

Comment: Nobody mentioned `eprintf` because that's not a standard C library function.

Comment: @AdrianMole Oh.

Answer (score -8):

To print your context, you can write code like this:

```
FILE *fp;
char *of;
sprintf(of, "%s%s", text1, text2);
fp = fopen(of, 'w');
fprintf(fp, "your print line");
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the previous answers and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: That sprintf() statement causes memory corruption! ...I highly advise you read up on how pointers, arrays, and strings work.